# Boundes for the distance between points of nested balls

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a vector space, $d$ a metric,  $a \in X$, $r>0$ and $B_{r}(a):=\{x \in X: d(a,x)\leq r\}$ (i.e. the closed ball around $a$ with radius $r>0$).

Let $a\in X$, $0 < r_{1}<r_{2}$ and define the two balls $B_{r_{1}}(a)$ and $B_{r_{2}}(a)$. Obviously $B_{r_{1}}(a) \subset B_{r_{2}}(a)$.

I'm trying to prove that the distance between $B_{r_{1}}(a)$ and an arbitrary element of $B_{r_{2}}(a)$ is bounded by $r_{2}-r_{1}>0$, i.e. $d(B_{r_{1}}(a),y):=\inf_{x \in B_{r_{1}}(a)}d(x,y)\leq r_{2}-r_{1}$ for all $y \in B_{r_{2}}$.

**Proof:**

Since  $d(B_{r_{1}}(a),y):=\inf_{x \in B_{r_{1}}(a)}d(x,y) = 0$ for $y \in B_{r_{1}}(a)$ I'll assume $y \in B_{r_{2}}(a)\setminus B_{r_{1}}(a)$.

Let's define the ball $B_{r_{2}-r_{1}}(y)$. Then $B_{r_{2}-r_{1}}(y) \cap B_{r_{1}} (a) \subset B_{r_{1}}(a)$.

If $B_{r_{2}-r_{1}}(y) \cap B_{r_{1}} \neq \emptyset$ then

$$
d(B_{r_{1}}(a),y)
=
inf_{x \in B_{r_{1}}(a)}d(x,y)
\leq
inf_{x \in B_{r_{2}-r_{1}}(y) \cap B_{r_{1}} (a)} d(x,y)
\leq r_{2}-r_{1}
$$

since any $x \in B_{r_{2}-r_{1}}(y)$ satisfies $ d(x,y)\leq r_{2}-r_{1}$ by construction.

I'll therefore prove that $B_{r_{2}-r_{1}}(y)\cap B_{r_{1}}(a)\neq \emptyset$ by contradiction.
Assume $B_{r_{2}-r_{1}}(y)\cap B_{r_{1}}(a) = \emptyset$ then $d(a,x)>r_{1}$ for all $x\in B_{r_{2}-r_{1}}(y)$.
Using the reverse triangular inequality twice, with $x \notin B_{r_{1}}(a)$ and $z \notin B_{r_{2}-r_{1}}(y)$, this implies

$$\begin{align}
d(a,y)
&\geq 
|d(a,x)-d(x,y)|\\
&\geq
|d(a,x)-|d(x,z)-d(z,y)||\\
&\geq
|d(x,a)-|0-d(z,y)||\\
&=
|d(a,x)-d(z,y)|\\
&>
r_{1}+(r_{2}-r_{1})|\\
&=
r_{2}
\end{align}
$$

Hence $d(a,y)>r_{2}$ but this is a contradiction since $y\in B_{r_{2}}(a)$.

Is the proof correct? I have the feeling that my approach is a little complicated and there should be a faster way to prove this.

**Update**

As my previous proof was wrong (see comments below) here is an updated version. Thanks to angryavian and Anne Bauval. Furthermore the metric is required to be induced by a norm which adds homegeneity to the properties we can use.

Let $y\in B_{r_{2}}(a)$. Define $z:=a+\frac{r_{1}}{d(a,y)}(y-a)$.

Then $d(z,a)=||z-a||=||a+\frac{r_{1}}{d(a,y)}(y-a)-a||=r_{1}$ and hence $z\in B_{r_{1}}(a)$.
It also holds that $d(z,y)=||z-y||=||a+\frac{r_{1}}{d(a,y)}(y-a)-y||=\frac{d(a,y)}{d(a,y)}(d(a,y)-r_{1})\leq r_{2}-r_{1}$

Hence $d(B_{r_{1}}(a),y):=\inf_{x \in B_{r_{1}}(a)}d(x,y)\leq r_{2}-r_{1}$

Comment: Can you say more about $X$? This isn't true for arbitrary metric spaces (e.g. suppose $X = \{a, b\}$ with $d(a, b) = r_2$, then $B_{r_1}(a)=\{a\}$ and $B_{r_2}(a) = \{a, b\}$). Should we assume $X$ is a vector space over the reals? If so then it is simpler to define $z := a + \frac{r_1}{d(a, y)} (y-a)$ so that $y \in B_{r_1}(a)$ and $d(B_{r_1}(a), y) \le d(z, y) = r_2-r_1$.

Comment: $d(a,x)-d(x,y)\le
d(a,x)-|d(x,z)-d(z,y)|$ is true but $|d(a,x)-d(x,y)|\geq
|d(a,x)-|d(x,z)-d(z,y)||$ may be false.

Comment: Similarly, $d(a,x)-|d(x,z)-d(z,y)|\ge
d(x,a)-|0-d(z,y)|$ is true but $|d(a,x)-|d(x,z)-d(z,y)||\ge
|d(x,a)-|0-d(z,y)||$ may be false.

Comment: @angryavian $X$ is a vector space.

Comment: @AnneBauval I think this should hold since $d(\cdot,\cdot)\geq 0$, but I'll think about this.

Comment: "$X$ is a vector space", or even "a vector space over the reals" is not a sufficient hypothesis. E.g. $X=\Bbb R,$ $d=$ the discrete metric, $r_2=1,$ $r_1=1/2.$ Note that in this example, if $x,y,z,a$ are distinct then $|d(a,x)-d(x,y)|=0<1=|d(a,x)-|d(x,z)-d(z,y)||.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Oops yes, I had the Euclidean metric in mind when writing the end of my comment.

Comment: Hm. Seems like my proof is wrong. But is the claim itself wrong? What happens if we exclude the discrete metric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample to the first of your two doubtful inequalities, namely
$$|d(a,x)-d(x,y)|\geq |d(a,x)-|d(x,z)-d(z,y)||.$$
Let $r_1=1,r_2=3,$ and in $X=\Bbb R^2$ with the usual Euclidean metric, let
$$a=(0,0),\quad y=(2,0)\in B_{r_{2}}(a)\setminus B_{r_{1}}(a),\quad x=(3,0)\notin B_{r_{1}}(a),\quad z=(2,3)\notin B_{r_{2}-r_{1}}(y).$$
Then,
$$d(a,x)-d(x,y)=2<3-(\sqrt{10}-3)=d(a,x)-|d(x,z)-d(z,y)|.$$

I don't feel necessary to search a counterexample to the second doubtful inequality.

Your claim itself is wrong if the metric on your vector space is arbitrary (even if the vector space is over the reals and the metric is not the discrete one). I leave it to you to find a counterexample.

On the other hand, if the metric is induced by a norm, the claim is easy to prove: see
angryavian's comment (which works for any norm, not necessarily Euclidean).

Comment: My bad. I was always thinking about the metric induced by the euclidean norm. The key point is the homogeneity of the norm.

Comment: Note that even with the metric induced by the euclidean norm, your proof was wrong, as shown by my counterexample.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'll update my proof.

Comment: What does MSE mean?

Comment: MathStackExchange. I agree with your update. You could say "was wrong (see comments and answer below)", and credit angryavian for the new proof.